# How to use jquery to disable click event of a DIV within a link?

Tags: jquery

There's a link in the DIV

```
<div><a href="#">go</a></div>
```

Can I disable click event on the DIV, but still works on the link?

I use this for test, but seems not work:

```
$(this).click(function(event){
    var _self_link=$('a',this);
    if(event.target!=_self_link){dosomething}
});
```

Any solution with Jquery? Thanks.

Comment: make click event not on the div, but in the <a>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use [stopPropagation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29).

> Stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
$('div:has(a[href="your_link"])').click(function(e) {
    stopPropagation();
});
```

You can test it here http://jsfiddle.net/cnzvL/13/

Comment: no he wants the div to prevent default. Not the anchor. might want to change the answer before I downvote

Comment: @Laurence, I just tested this code on jsFiddle, and the value of $(this) is div, not anchor, so I think the answer is correct. The div is preventing the default action.

Comment: yes now it will work with the first representation you were selecting the anchor not the div. will remove my downvote.

Comment: This is my solution. Thanks guys.

    $('DIV').click(function(event){
     var click_on_href=false;
     $("a",'DIV').click(function(event){
         event.stopPropagation();
         click_on_href=true;
     }); 
            if(!click_on_href){dosomething}
    });

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // and then do what you want
});
```

Edited: maybe I didn't understand the question correctly. Here is the second variant:

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    // and then do what you want
});
```