# Disable jQuery .click

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div tag :

```
<div class="i2Style" id="mydiv" >Check  Domain</div>
```

And Javascript :

```
$("#mydiv").click(function abc(){...}
```

And i want to disable this **.click** during execution of function **abc()** because i don't want user click that div until that function executing . What is the solution ?

Comment: simply using `.one()` http://api.jquery.com/one/ or rather `.on()` and `.off()`

Comment: `.one()` or in the function `$(this).unbind("click");`. More on [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>**[EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/icoluw/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
function abc(){

  $("#mydiv").off('click', abc);     // off click
  alert('Wait ~2s please');          // do stuff


  var tim = setTimeout(function(){
       $("#mydiv").on('click', abc); // reset click
  },2000);                           

}


$("#mydiv").on('click', abc);        // run fn
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try various ways

1. [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)
2. global variable
   etc.

refer
[How to use jquery to disable click event of a DIV within a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342578/how-to-use-jquery-to-disable-click-event-of-a-div-within-a-link)